# How to set up Renovate Bot for Gitlab including private dependencies?

Tags: gitlab, dependency-management, renovate

I have successfully configured Renovate Bot to run on a schedule by following the instructions presented in this GitLab repository - https://gitlab.com/renovate-bot/renovate-runner. The problem is that Renovate Bot is able to only recognize public dependencies used within Gitlab repositories.

According to the documentation - https://docs.renovatebot.com/modules/platform/gitlab/#gitlab, I have created a PAT with all the necessary permissions and added RENOVATE_HOST_RULES CI variable:

```
WARN: Package lookup failures (repository=my-group/my-subgroup/my-project)
43       "warnings": [
44         "Failed to look up npm package @my-group/my-deps-repo-1",
45         "Failed to look up npm package @my-group/my-deps-repo-2",
46         "Failed to look up npm package @my-group/my-deps-repo-3"
47       ],
48       "files": ["package.json"]
```

Comment: If you enable debug logs, do they contain more info?

Comment: Switched the log level to DEBUG. Here are the host rules:

"hostRules": [
           {"hostType": "gitlab", "matchHost": "gitlab.com", "token": "***********"},
           {"hostType": "github", "matchHost": "github.com", "token": "***********"}
         ]

But still, it fails to look up npm packages stored in our private Gitlab package registry:

GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@my-group%2Fmy-deps-repo = (code=ERR_NON_2XX_3XX_RESPONSE, statusCode=404.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think specifying `hostRules` is enough.

To configure a custom NPM registry, we use the following configuration:

```json
{
  "npmrc": "registry=https://private-registry.company.net/npm/\n@companyprefix:registry=https://private-registry.company.net/npm-companyprefix/"
}
```

Which is basically the content you'd have in your `.npmrc` file.

(Adapt to your need)

Answer (score 0):

I ran also into that issue today and I fixed it by adding a `config.js` as described [here](https://docs.renovatebot.com/getting-started/private-packages/#npm). You need to modify the `my-group` to your groups name. Renovate should then pick up the correct registry.

The config is for a GitLab job, that's why we are using the `CI_JOB_TOKEN` instead of a PAT.

```
module.exports = {
  npmrc: "@my-group:registry=https://gitlab.com/api/v4/packages/npm/",
  hostRules: [
    {
      hostType: "npm",
      matchHost: "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/packages/npm/",
      token: process.env.CI_JOB_TOKEN,
    },
  ],
};
```